# Can a Z/OS mainframe application or DB2 read a SQL Server database/table directly?

Tags: db2

Is there anything similar to ODBC that would allow DB2 on a Z/OS mainframe platform to read a Microsoft SQL Server database/table.

Answer (score 3):

Define read...

You can certainly run a Java application on z/OS that uses JDBC to connect and transfer data from MS SQL Server into DB2 for z/OS.

Otherwise, IBM's distributed database protocol is known as Distributed Relational Database Architecture (DRDA).

Both IBM and Microsoft offer products that allow MS SQL server to be seen as a remote DB2 server.
[Microsoft Service for DRDA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130703.aspx)
[IBM InfoSphere Federation Server](https://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibminfofedeserv)

With the IBM product, you'd need a DB2 LUW server in the middle.

On IBM's midrange platform, IBM i (aka AS/400), there exists an open-source DRDA-JDBC gateway, [ArdGate](https://sourceforge.net/projects/appserver4rpg/).  I don't know if something similar exists for z/OS or if you could port the project or build one yourself.